# How to combine Infinite Scroll with Photoset Grid?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, tumblr

**Update: this is not loading annything: What is wrong with this code?**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://static.tumblr.com/snscsmd/Z3ln6cev3/jquery.infinitescroll.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$('#content').infinitescroll({
// infinite scroll settings
}, function(newPosts){
$(newPosts)
.wrapAll('<div class="photoset-grid">') //wrap them in place
.parent() //get .photoset-grid
.photosetGrid({
    //photoset grid settings
});
});
</script>
```

**My problem is to combine [Infinite Scroll](https://github.com/paulirish/infinite-scroll) with [Photoset Grid](https://github.com/stylehatch/photoset-grid/).** I need a callback but I am not sure how to implement it.

Website: http://sindreolsson.tumblr.com/

**HTML**

```
{block:Photoset}
<div class="photoset-grid" data-layout="{PhotosetLayout}" data-id="photoset{PostID}" style="visibility: hidden;" />
{block:Photos}
<img src="{PhotoURL-500}"
{block:HighRes}data-highres="{PhotoURL-HighRes}"{/block:HighRes}
width="{PhotoWidth-500}" height="{PhotoHeight-500}"
{block:Caption}alt="{Caption}"{/block:caption} />
{/block:Photos}
</div><!-- /.tumblr-photoset -->

{block:Caption}<div class="photoset-grid-copy">{Caption}</div>{/block:Caption}
{/block:Photoset}
```

**Script:**

```
<!--Photoset-grid script -->
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="http://static.tumblr.com/mviqmwg/XyYn59y3a/jquery.photoset-grid.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.photoset-grid').photosetGrid({
rel: $('.photoset-grid').attr("data-id"),
gutter: '0px',

onComplete: function(){
$('.photoset-grid').css({
    'visibility': 'visible'
});
}
});
});
</script>
<!-- /Photoset-grid script -->
```

Answer (score 1):

This should pull the new posts and wrap them in a new `div.photoset-grid`. At that point you can just call `.photosetGrid()` with your settings.

```
$('#content').infinitescroll({
    // infinite scroll settings
  }, function(newPosts){
    $(newPosts)
    .wrapAll('<div class="photoset-grid">') //wrap them in place
    .parent() //get .photoset-grid
    .photosetGrid({
        //photoset grid settings
    });
});
```

#### Previous answer

> It's not too clear on Infinite Scroll's repo, but on
>   [infinite-scroll.com](http://www.infinite-scroll.com/) you can see the
>   callback in their second example. Here's a **partial solution** using
>   that callback:
>
> ```
> $('#content').infinitescroll({
>     //settings
>   }, function(newPosts){
>     //MISSING: reset photosetGrid
>     $('.photoset-grid').photosetGrid();
> });
> ```
>
> Unfortunately it seems that an "update" or "reset" method is missing
>   for Photoset Grid, so perhaps [open an issue in their
>   repo](https://github.com/stylehatch/photoset-grid/issues/1) and *hope*
>   that if someone adds the functionality, it happens in time.
>
> Alternatively you can look for a different script.

Comment: Something like: `newPosts.find('.photoset-grid').photosetGrid();` should do the trick. (As long as `newPosts` is a jQuery Collection).

Comment: mikedidthis; do you have a complete code that will work with my theme? Infinite-scroll + photoset-grid.

Comment: @mikedidthis I would think that `.photoset-grid` is the container of all posts and `newPosts` a list of its _new_ children, not a new grid. But… I edited my answer, this might work.

Comment: @bfred.it `newPosts` is an array of new posts added to the DOM. `.photoset-grid` is the class given to each photoset element, which would be a child of a single `newPosts`.

Comment: I have updated my QS. @bfred.it. It is not showing up annything. Check it out: http://sindreolsson.tumblr.com

Comment: Open the browser's console. You placed infinitescroll before jQuery

Comment: I have fixed it, still nothing happends @bfred.it

Comment: Infinite Scroll is not working. Fix that. Initialize it this way to see what's happening `.infiniteScroll({debug:true})`

Comment: I am really bad when it comes to scrips. How do I make it work? @bfred.it

Comment: You might have to hire someone… or ask a new question on StackOverflow